# Safety of C# DataTable as SQL Parameter

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-injection

I read a lot about SQL injections lately and I know a `SqlParameter` will not prevent injections for sure, but is a table parameter as safe as a single parameter?

Some untested uncompiled example code for clarification:

Is this...

SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertSingle 
    @Name nvarchar(max),
    @Phone nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    INSERT INTO FooBar.dbo.SomeTable 
    VALUES(@Name, @Phone)
END
GO
```

C#:

```
foreach(User u in Users) 
{
     Connection.Open();

     SqlCommand com = Connection.CreateCommand();
     com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     com.CommandText = "dbo.InsertSingle";

     SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@Name", u.Name);
     com.Parameters.Add(p);

     p = new SqlParameter("@Phone", u.Phone);
     com.Parameters.Add(p);

     com.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

as safe as this?

SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertBunch 
    @ValuesAsTable dbo.ValuesAsTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO FooBar.dbo.SomeTable 
        SELECT * 
        FROM @ValuesAsTable
END
GO
```

C#:

```
DataTable valuesAsTable = Users.GetSomeInsertData();
Connection.Open();

SqlCommand com = Connection.CreateCommand();
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com.CommandText = "dbo.InsertBunch";

SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@valuesAsTable", valuesAdTable);
p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
p.TypeName = "dbo.ValuesAsTableType";
com.Parameters.Add(p);

com.ExecuteScalar();
```

I really tried to search it, but I cannot find good input. Can anyone link me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You declared a type on the table already.  If you want it to be even stronger pass the field names instead of `select *` and use `WITH SCHEMABINDING`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typed parameters will prevent SQL injection if there is no possibility that they get interpreted as literal commands, and executed. Whether they are transported as scalar or table-valued parameters, does not make any difference in this regard.